# How to loop a list into loc, isin and sum function

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I got a list of ID # from a CSV sheet. The list has an index of 200.  Using that list I was able to get the salary associated with the ID# from a data frame.

To match them I used this code below. a & b gets the salary from the data from matching the first ID number from the list called IDlist and sums up the listed salary.

```
a =df.loc[df['ID'].isin(IDlist[0])].sum(axis=0,skipna=True).loc['salary']
b =df.loc[df['ID'].isin(IDlist[1])].sum(axis=0,skipna=True).loc['salary']
```

Was super happy when I get the first 3. Then realized it would take me forever to get through 200.

Is there a way to loop this IDlist[0:200] individually without typing 200 of the same line above?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to get the data out but the simplest would be:

```
salaries = [df.loc[df['ID'].isin(IDlist[x])].sum(axis=0,skipna=True).loc['salary'] for x in range(0,200)]
```

You could get fancier and use a dict comprehension if you want to map id to salary:

```
salaries = {IDlist[x]:df.loc[df['ID'].isin(IDlist[x])].sum(axis=0,skipna=True).loc['salary'] for x in range(0,200)}
```

I'm assuming some things about the way your data is structured but I think that would give you a dictionary of ids tied to salaries.

Comment: thank you so much. I can now go to bed as a happy camper